# Run a sh file when starting a service (with PM2 or systemd)

Tags: systemd, debian

I need help please to finish something. (I use Debian 11).

I'm looking for a solution so that an sh file I created, automatically runs when a service (which I also created myself) has finished restarting.

My service is a service that runs a Node.js App. Here it is (with PM2):

```
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: "nextjs_mon-site-prod_1",
      cwd: "/home/steph/www/mon-site.com/prod/front-nextjs_1",
      script: "npm run start_prod_1", // and then I want to run an sh script
    },
  ],
};
```

I prefer to do this with PM2 (although I'm open to solutions with systemd).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You've not provided any OS/release/product details; but have tagged the question relates to a *deb* packaging or workflow issue, which doesn't seem to fit your question - please clarify & provide OS & release details.

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.